# Microsoft docs code producing errors in Microsoft Studio

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, msdn

I've only created c++ console apps until recently, winapi is still new, so maybe I'm just missing something.

When using code from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com) I've been getting errors in Visual Studio about incompatible types. Until now I've been changing or overriding variables. Figured it's time to do it right.

An example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window

If I copy paste the final example into a working visual studio project I get multiple errors:

[image]

[image]

As it is Microsoft code, and Microsoft Software, I would have thought it wouldn't need changing.

Comment: This can only go wrong when you created the project from scratch instead of using the project template.  Not a great idea.  The specific setting that is wrong is Project > Properties > General > "Character Set".  The world, and code samples, speaks Unicode.

Comment: You'll likely miss out on a lot of other goodies, particularly the instrumenting you get to diagnose UB in a program is extremely useful.  Do use a project template.

Comment: @HansPassant Up until now I have used the default char set, In the current version is it Project > Properties > Advanced > "Character Set" and it is set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" And changing it to unicode did actually fix it. But I'm not sure it answered the question completely, Is there a reason MS code doesn't work in MS software by default, or is there an intro page or link I'm missing?

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate on missing out on other goodies? and what UB is?

Comment: MBCS is not the default in any project template, you're not telling me enough to know why it was set wrong.  MS code samples do assume you use the IDE as intended.  UB is "undefined behavior", an aspect of C and C++ code that very easily creates very hard to diagnose bugs.  Get ahead with [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @HansPassant That article was a nice read. MBCS is definitely the default on my VS Community 2019. There isn't any other information, it's a fairly fresh install, and a newly created project. If you want to put Unicode into an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

LPCSTR is defined as const char*, not const wchar_t*. Use LPCWSTR, or LPCTSTR you should with UNICODE defined.